# Easy pattern to convert Node-style callback functions to await/async

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is there some easy pattern that supports auto-magically converting Node-style `func(params, callback)` functions to await/async compatible.

I know I can convert them to promises myself, but I was wondering if since that pattern has become so common now, if there wasn't some Babel package or something that is smart enough to automatically allow us to just use them, or if I'd have to convert them all to Promises myself?

To convert it to a Promise function I can just do this (using `fs.readFile` as an example):

```
import { readFile } from 'fs';

const readFilePromise = path => new Promise((resolve, reject) => readFile(path, (err, data) => err && reject(err) || resolve(data)));
```

That's simple enough, but it's a pain to have to convert every function I want in that fashion.

Comment: `err && reject(err) || resolve(data)` really should be `err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)`

Comment: Yes, you can abstract this out into a helper function (or just use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)). Or use more advanced tools like `Bluebird.promisifyAll`.

Comment: There also are a few npm libs that expose a promisified filesystem API etc, but lib requests are off-topic on SO and I cannot recommend a specific one.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. And yeah, I'm aware of them for libraries that promisify the native libraries already. The actual ones I'm working on don't already have promise libraries. Just used `fs` as an easy example.